# Keycloak create script mapper for custom attribute

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to create script mapper in the new quarkus distribution. I want to use it to create an custom attribute for the token which will have my custom roles displayed. I am able to create the custom attribute caled **custom_roles** in the token as follows:

"custom_roles":[
"default-roles-5plcm",
"offline_access",
"Super Admin",
"uma_authorization"
]

but i want only **"Super Admin"** which is a custom role.

"custom_roles":["Super Admin"]

I have followed this article - "https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-custom-protocol-mapper" but I am unable to get the custom attribute that should be created from above.

Also, I have tried using the flag "-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled" to get the script feature enabled on the UI.

Kindly suggest me how I can acheived the mention feature OR let me know if there is a workaround for this.